# Browser back button - behavior on gray area changes (ie. list/grid view)

Tags: user-expectation, back-button

As in [this research](https://baymard.com/blog/back-button-expectations) mentions, you should not break the back button (and [Nielsen said it](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/the-top-ten-web-design-mistakes-of-1999/) as well).

My question is in regard to 2 separate edge cases:

From the homepage you search on an e-commerce site for 'blue shoes'.

1. You change the view from list to grid view and then click the browser back button.
2. You change the listings from 24 to 48 per page and then click the browser back button.

What would the user expect when he presses the back button in each of these cases -> a reset in view (ie. bring you from the selected grid view back to list view, still on the same page) or back to the previous page (ie. homepage)?

Comment: Good question! .

Answer (score 0):

You can not expect a mango tree to give you a coconut. Of course that almost every user will expect to return to the previous page instead of any other behavior just simply because that's the normal behavior of the browser's back button.
Now, that said, you can modify the back button to fit your needs but you have to consider of it is absolutely necessary because you are breaking the normal journey of the user and you must have a real good reason for doing that.

Comment: Please check the first link in the question.
The idea is not about whether it is useful to change the browser back button, but what is the expected behavior from the user when he presses the back button in the 2 cases mentioned above.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your question is this **Should the back button in each case reset the change in view, or bring you back to the homepage?** and it was what I answered. What you say now, **what is the expected behavior from the user when he presses the back button in the 2 cases mentioned above?** is something else. In this case the expected behaviour of a standard user is trying to return to tthe page where he/she was before. If you need a clearer answer, please provide then a clearer question.

Comment: Fair point, clarified the question.

Comment: Updated answer too.

Comment: The question is - what is the expected behavior, or more precise - what does the user see as back to the previous page?

Is back to the 'page' where it had 24 instead of 48 items, or is it back to the homepage.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. If you ask what's the browser's back button behavior you already know that it goes to the previous page. What you have to determine is which would be the previous page because programmatically you can alter the default behavior of the browser's back button.

Comment: Yes the browser back button goes to the previous page. The problem is what the user sees as a previous page. It could be the 'page' (in quotations because technically it does not have to be a separate page) where you had 24 items listed or it could be the homepage.

Example: go to this item https://ebay.to/3xt0Itn and press 'Bezahlung' (https://imgur.com/a/Perdlzp). Now what would you expect from the back button  to do? Bring you back one step (ie stay on item with Beschreibung section open, not Bezahlung, or go back out of the item page to the page before).

Comment: Well,  I finally understood the problem. Browser history is a two way path. Depending on the way you have built your site the previous page would be the 24 items listed or whatever page the usera was before. For example. I've got this app I'm working on right now. The user gets to a page where he can press a button to fill up a buying form. But this form is built in a pop over which technically is the same page, so if she/him presses the back button he/she will be prompted to the previous page which could be the home page or any other depending on where he/she came from on his journey.

Comment: Exactly. But you can decide (one way is mentioned in the article with history pushstate) if some parts should be seen by the browser as separate pages, to accomodate the expectations of the user.

And the question is - what is the expectation of the user in such cases. Taking your example - would the user expect with the back button to go 'back' to the same page (same page, only with closed pop over). According to the article, this would be a good case to leave the user on the same page, and only close the pop over (if it is a big pop over).

Answer (score 0):

If I were your user, my expectation is backing to the place which I previously come from, so refer to your user case, here is my answer

> You change the view from list to grid view and then click the browser
> back button.

Back to the grid view.

> You change the listings from 24 to 48 per page and then click the
> browser back button.

Back to the 24 per page.

Answer (score 0):

> You change the view from list to grid view and then click the browser back button.

If the list/ grid toggle action is persistent - say, it remains in the title bar - then the user is more likely to expect the back button to return then to the homepage. Otherwise, they are likely to expect the other view.

[image: Title bar with view list icon]

> You change the listings from 24 to 48 per page and then click the browser back button.

Because changing the # of items is the list is similar to scrolling for more results, I believe that users will expect a back button to return them to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the question you need to ask is: *Does changing the view mode **feels** like a new page?*

Because (also as per your linked article) that is what users expect from the back button: It bringing you back to the previous "page".

Now, personally I don't think grid/list view toggling or changing the number of listings is "a new page", so I would expect the back button to bring me to whatever the actual previous page was (homepage etc). However, I am not your user!

If for example your target group is less adept with handling complex UIs, an action that completely changes the UI (list/grid switch) they might go "Oh no! What happened? Take me back! But in *this case*, `back` would mean to the other view, not the homepage.

### TLDR:

Either do a best guess based on whether you feel it's a "new page" or do A/B testing based user research.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the "back" button in the browser always takes you to the preceding page. This is not only about user experience but also about development infrastructure.

Modifying the display of products does not entail navigating to a different page, so the "back" button will lead you back to the home page.

and when changing the list view from 24 to 48 products, no transition to another page occurs, and everything takes place on the same page. If, however, the product area were paginated like on Amazon, and I navigated to page 2, the "back" button would indeed return me to page 1.

**This is a development infrastructure that cannot be altered**, and it's beneficial, as it aligns with what users are accustomed to.